# A woman with a unique trait, a special spark

Tags: phrase-request

In Russian, when one wants to describe a woman that has some special trait in her that makes her stand out, some tiny spark in her character, a pinch of salt making her flavor special, so to speak, he sometimes tends to use the phrase "A woman with a raisin (in her)." That is, *Женщина с изюминкой*. Like a bun that is made unique by the addition of a single raisin.

I wonder what counterpart idioms in English exist. "A woman with a special charm"? "A charm of her own"? A woman with a certain piquancy? Maybe there's more.

P.S. It's a question [asked](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?a=4&MessNum=305962&l1=1&l2=2) at one forum by a translator.

Comment: 'She's very *bubbly*'?

Comment: What kind of "special trait" does the raisin refer to? Beauty? Wisdom? Charm? Vivaciousness? Kindness? Cool under pressure? Or could it be any or all of those?

Comment: I believe it could be any of those, @J.R.

Comment: "one in a million", perhaps?

Comment: If you wanted to allude to several positive traits all at once, there's the term _Proverbs 31 woman_, which refers to the "capable" wife (or "virtuous", or "excellent", or "noble", depending on your Bible translation) depicted in a poem at the end of Proverbs. @DamkerngT. - I love "one in a million" – of course, that term could be applied to a man just as easily as a woman, but I still think it captures the informal charm of the raisin analogy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the page titled “List of French words and phrases used by English speakers”, Wikipedia has:

> **je ne sais quoi**
>
> lit. "I-don't-know-what": an indescribable or indefinable 'something' that distinguishes the object in question from others that are superficially similar. ([Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_French_words_and_phrases_used_by_English_speakers#J))

This term is often applied to people who have qualities that set them apart, especially when these qualities are intangible and difficult to describe.

It is widely used in English, but you could also say someone has “a certain something” if you are particularly interested in using words that have been more thoroughly incorporated into the language.

<sup>*As evidence of its prevalence, it is the subject of a joke made by Mike Myers in the second Austin Powers movie:*</sup>

> <sup>***Dr. Evil:** Mojo; the libido; the life force; the essence; the right stuff. What the French call a certain... I don't know what.*</sup>

---

There is also the related concept of an [“it” girl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It_girl), about which Rudyard Kipling says:

> It isn't beauty, so to speak, nor good talk necessarily. It's just “It”.

I have only ever heard it applied to women who attract men, but Elinor Glyn says:

> With “It” you win all men if you are a woman and all women if you are a man. “It” can be a quality of the mind as well as a physical attraction.

So you’d be reasonably justified in simply saying [(or singing)](http://www.lyricsmode.com/lyrics/l/little_richard/shes_got_it.html) “she’s got *It*.”

Answer (score 2):

***She's [quite striking](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/striking)***

Perhaps she doesn't conform to today's standard of beauty, but there's something about her that makes you stop and admire her.

She has something special which makes [**her stand out from the crowd**](http://www.wikihow.com/Stand-Out-from-the-Crowd).